# How to setup alfresco's latest community version using maven?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-maven

Currently only `org.alfresco.maven.archetype:alfresco-platform-jar-archetype 3.0.1` which installs *5.2.f version* is available through the `command:mvn archetype:genresco:-Dfilter=org.alfresco`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the last version of the Alfresco SDK is still the 3.0.1, and it is not compatible with the lastest version of Alfresco Community.

If I read correctly the [Alfresco Community Edition 201806 GA Release Notes](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-7381-draft-alfresco-community-edition-201805-ga-release-draft) :

> **SDK**
>
> The Alfresco SDK is not yet updated with the new code locations.
> For more details, see [More of Alfresco Content Services on GitHub](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-7133-more-of-alfresco-content-services-on-github).
>
> **Known Issues**
>
> The Alfresco SDK is not yet compatible with this release.